# Unable to find the source of network call in Google Developer Network tab

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

A text/html request is made from the website and in the debugger tool the initiator of the request is p.expr.filter.hidden.

I'm confused how this can make a network call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code a css property was set as below

```
style= "background: url('')"
```

This snippet (specially the url function) was resulting in a network call.

Not sure why in the chrome network debugger it was pointing to some other code snippet as the source of the request.

So In case you don't find the source of a request, also give a look into css properties.